# Reallocating dynamically allocated struct

Tags: c

I searched for an answer but didn't manage to find one.

I have a dynamically allocated struct, which means the structure itself will be allocated and some of its members. Like:

```
typedef struct dataUse
{
    char *num;
    char *name;
    char *position;
    char *eMail;
    float upload;
    float download;
} DataUse;

DataUse *ptr = NULL;
```

Now I have functions to reallocate memory for `*ptr` and also for `*name`, `*position`, `*eMail`. The size of `name`, `position` and `eMail` varies of course.

Now I understand, that reallocating something will either keep the original address of the data and increase the memory size or if it can't allocate to the same space, it will copy its contents and assign the pointer a new address.

Now in my case, if I reallocate my `struct` (`*ptr`) and want to increase its size and the latter happens, meaning my structs contents will be copied and new address will be signed, what will happen to `*name`, `*position` and `*email`? Can I still access them and the old contents via `ptr->num`. Will I have some kind of memory loss?

I'd just like someone to verify what will happen and explain, how it would look in memory if I realloc the whole struct. I'v seen, how structs look like in memory I've read a ton of posts, but sometimes it will get a bit confusing after adding some more pointers and going deeper levels (using double pointer for instance).

And what would happen, if I'd do it with double pointers - `**ptr2` to hold pointers that will point to structs and then realloc `**ptr2` to hold even more pointers?

Comment: What?  'if I reallocate my struct ' - your struct is fixed-size!

Comment: Anytime you find yourself asking "how it would look in memory", consider it firm jab in the ribs for firing up a debugger on the platform you're running this on and actually *doing that* : I.e. *looking at memory*. How it actually "looks" is better demonstrated there than anywhere else.

Comment: @Martin James- My struct is not fixed. I have a function, that will add memory to my struct ex:  `void allocStruct(DataUse **ptr) { allocate memory here }`.

Comment: Short reply: "Can I still access them and the old contents via ptr->num." --> yes.  "Will I have some kind of memory loss?" --> no.  But if you **posted the code**, we could detect if there is a difference between what you said and what you coded that is causing (or may cause) an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you have allocated an instance of `DataUse` and store the address in `ptr`. Now you are reallocating it.

Pointers stores absolute address, so reallocating struct containing pointers won't lose the data.

So the instance of `DataUse` lies in somewhere in the memory, its address stored in `ptr`. The data of `num` lies in some other place, its address stored in the `num` field in `DataUse`. When copying the instance of `DataUse` to another place, the `num` field is also copied, so the address of string num and name etc remains unchanged and are still in the new copy of `num`, `name` fields.

You just reallocate the struct, i.e. the positions where you store addresses are changed, but the addresses held in `num`, `name`, ... remains unchanged.

Comment: "but the addresses of..." um, "the addresses *held* in..." is considerably more accurate. The addresses *of* those members will change as soon as you change the address of the struct containing them.

Comment: @songziming Yes. I want to allocate *ptr to store more structs. So if I understand correctly, if my struct will be copied and memory added, I can access previously stored structs and it's members throug *ptr?

Answer (score 0):

If we assume `ptr[i]` is valid (e.g. an array of at least `i+1` `DataUse` has previously been allocated using `malloc()`), and the size of the memory that `ptr` points to is increased using `realloc()`, then the address of  `ptr[i].num` will change if `ptr` has changed, but the value of `ptr[i].num` will not.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following snippets:

```
DataUse *ptr= malloc(sizeof(DataUse));    // allocate non-zeroed memory
```

The above allocates memory for your structure. Note that it is not zeroed, so anything that should be zeroed must be zeroed by you.

```
ptr->name= malloc(strlen(this_name)+1);
strcpy(ptr->name, this_name);
```

The above initializes `name`.

```
free(ptr_name);
ptr->name= malloc(strlen(new_name)+1);
strcpy(ptr->name, new_name);
```

The above places a new name in `name`. It first frees the allocated memory.

```
char *tmpname= realloc(ptr->name, strlen(new_name)+1);
if (tmpname) {
    ptr->name= tmpname;
    strcpy(ptr->name, new_name);
}
else printf("Out of memory);
```

The above does (about) the same, but uses `realloc`. Note that `ptr->name` MUST be zero if it was not used before.